# insert json object with codecRegistry in Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing an issue while insert json object to mongo collection.
Using, mongodbdriver-sync 4.6.0, mongo-driver-core 4.6.0, bson 4.9.1

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DataModel {
  @JsonProperty("messageId")
  private String messageId;

  @JsonProperty("messageBody")
  private String messageBody;

  @JsonProperty("status")
  private String status;
}
```

compling is good and i can connect to mongoDB but it throws exception, `...CodecConfigurationException: Unable to get value for property 'message' in DataModel.`

It seems it's throwing an error due to the missing `message` which is  optional property. How to fix this issue? I need to handle many optional properties.

```java
CodecRegistry myRegistry = fromRegistries(
MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
 fromProviders( 
  PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(DataModel.class).build()
 )
);

MongoCollection<IndexDataModel> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("collectioname", DataModel.class).withCodecRegistry(myRegistry);

InsertOneResult result = collection.insertOne(dataModel);
```